# how to authenticate CRM user using web api?

Tags: c#, api, oauth, dynamics-crm, crm

I have an API address which gets data from CRM. When I try to get data from that API by writing this API in the browser's address bar, I face an error `401` which is an authentication error. I have credentials but don't know how to use them in a request.

Comment: Which CRM are you trying to access? It is impossible to answer without more details from your side.

Comment: How to authenticate from code: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh675404.aspx otherwise are you calling  a rest service or using the discovery service

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you looked at the samples located here: [Basic Operations with web API preview](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Basic-Operations-with-web-67fc1d8f)

I've also got some sample code on GitHub: [CrmWebApiCSharp](https://github.com/jlattimer/CrmWebApiCSharp)

Using the ADAL library, authentication would look something like this:

```
AuthenticationContext authContext =
new AuthenticationContext(_authority, false);
```

//Prompt for credentials
//_authResult = authContext.AcquireToken(
//  _serviceUrl, _clientId, new Uri(_redirectUrl));

//No prompt for credentials
UserCredential credentials = new UserCredential(_username, _password);
_authResult = authContext.AcquireToken(
    _serviceUrl, _clientId, credentials);

Comment: i want to do it with javascript

Comment: JavaScript in the browser won't work until CRM 2016 - CORS isn't supported in the 2015 implementation. I'd look at the ADAL library for JavScript https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js